# Why are files deleted by Files.move() when an AccessDeniedException is thrown?

Tags: java, java.nio.file

This is just meant as a conceptional question. I am using `Files.move()` with the `StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE` option. I thought that would be safer, but turned out the files are still deleted when an AccessDeniedException is thrown.

Any work around or explanation is appreciated.

Code is very simple:

```
Files.move(netDirJobs.toPath(), archiveJobs.toPath(),StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
```

OS: win7 Professional SP1

@MarkJeronimus :

```
netDirLog.toPath().getFileSystem().provider()  = sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider@5dac9e07
archiveLog.toPath().getFileSystem().provider() = sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider@5dac9e07
```

Jup same object

Comment: According to the Docu "ATOMIC_MOVE" means something else: With an ATOMIC_MOVE you can move a file into a directory and be guaranteed that any process watching the directory accesses a complete file.

Comment: Now since this would be a fatal flaw on the filesystem's side, you're going to have to prove that this really happens. Personally I think your problem is elsewhere, since a filesystem that would cause data loss in a case like this would simply be broken.

Comment: I'd like some help in debugging. Are the files both on the same filesystem? Can you do `path.getFileSystem().provider()` on both src and dst paths, and check if the results are the same object? (compares with `==`)

Comment: @MarkJeronimus edited your answer into the question.

Comment: I could only trace it to the MSDN call [MoveFileEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexa) where I hit a dead end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys thanks for the effort.

First some additional information:
 I am moving the data two times, first from source to a temporary and then to the final destination.

The error message mislead me to think it was a problem of Files.move(). But what really happens was that it moved the files correctly to the temporary directory which then of course got deleted for being just temporary. I removed the delete on exit command for the temporary directory and now if the move from the temporary directory to the destination fails it is still saved in the temporary as I intended.

Sorry for the unnecessary question.

And special thanks to Mark Jeronimus for looking into it even after 4 days have past.